# How do you access files in deployed AppService webapp?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Dockerized Django-based webapp to AppService (Linux) using Github Actions.

My application has a 4.2MB .csv file which I'd like access to for certain functionality within the app. To access the file when deployed, I understand that I can upload it to Blob Storage and then download the file e.g. with `get_blob_client(my_blob).download_blob()`

However, I was wondering whether the .csv file is available within the deployed version of the app? I feel it would be less resource-intensive to access the file within the app, rather than pull it from 'remote' blob storage (but, admittedly, I don't understand Azure's architecture well enough to say whether this hunch is correct.)

When developing locally, my file is in `approot/app/data/myfile.csv` and I can load the .csv with `open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'data/myfile.csv'))`. When deployed, however, I get a file not found error as the path `approot/app/data/` obviously doesn't exist on the remote server.

My questions: does `myfile.csv` get uploaded to my AppService instance when deployed? If so, where does the file live and how could I access it? (Environment variable, presumably?) If this is possible, would this indeed be a better approach than downloading the file from blob storage, given the file size and the frequency it will be accessed (I predict a few hundred times per day)

Comment: You can check via "Advanced Tools" / Kudu if you need to view the file system. Its URL is `https://yourappservice.scm.azurewebsites.net`, so just add "scm" sub-domain in between your app name and the standard domain. There you can go to Debug Console to view the file system.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've had a poke around and I can't really see anything file system-wise. I can see `https://yourappservice.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot` but the only file in there is something called `hostingstart.html`. Am I looking in the right place?

Comment: Ah, is your app deployed as a container? Sorry, I mainly use Windows App Service and this could be different.

Comment: Ah yes, it is. I forgot to mention that in the question. Dockerized app, with a PostGres DB on Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can access/View  Deployed files in FileZilla/ WinSCP.
Download [FileZilla Client](https://filezilla-project.org/) or  WinSCP_Setup.exe file from google and Install.
Enter the Hostname , username and password from the azure portal.
To get the End Point,Username and Password details, login to Azure Portal.

Go to Deployment Center -- > FTP Credentials ,
Copy the Required Hostname (FTPS endpoint), username and Password and paste in WinSCP Setup/FileZilla Client. In right side pane of WinSCP / FileZilla you will find the files of your deployed application.

[image]

Comment: I've connected using FileZilla, however still only see an empty `wwwroot` folder